# dial tcp: lookup master on 10.151.0.1:53: no such host over expressvpn

Tags: server, kubernetes

I am building a k8s cluster.
but I am using expressvpn so when I am trying to make my worker join the msater its cant join and give me this error

> I0423 20:19:33.265427    5573 token.go:217] [discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get "https://master:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": dial tcp: lookup master on 10.151.0.1:53: no such host

when I nano

> /etc/resolv.conf

I find

> Generated by expressvpn
> search expressvpn
> nameserver 10.151.0.1